# How to optimize model parameters using sceua method in rtop package, R language

Tags: r, optimization, parameters, simulation

I am a student interested in hydrology and runoff-simulation.
I am using topmodel package in R with huagrahuma dataset, and I want to optimize its parameters by using sceua method in rtop package.
I wrote a code, using the example in "rtop package | R Documentation" as a reference.
However, I got an error when optimizing the parameters. It says "error in if (sum(mapply(FUN = function(x, y, z) max(y - x, x - z, 0),  :
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed". At first, I suspected the error was triggered by NA values which Qobs has. So I converted NA to numerical values but the same error has occurred again.
How can I optimize the parameters by SCE-UA method?

Links
topmodel function | R Documentation
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/topmodel/versions/0.7.3/topics/topmodel
Tutorial on the use of topmodel in R
https://paramo.cc.ic.ac.uk/topmodel_tutorial
topmodel: Implementation of the Hydrological Model TOPMODEL in R
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/topmodel/index.html
rtop package | R Documentation
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rtop/versions/0.5-14
rtop: Interpolation of Data with Variable Spatial Support
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rtop/index.html

```
install.packages("topmodel")
install.packages("Hmisc")
library(topmodel)
library(Hmisc)


# Then calculate the topographic index, the resolution should be in [m].
data(huagrahuma.dem)
DEM <- sinkfill(huagrahuma.dem, 25, 0.1)
topindex <- topidx(DEM, resolution=25)

# The values need to be split into a set of classes, since topmodel() is a semidistributed model that lumps hydrologically similar areas into the same hydrological response units.
# Here we define 16 hydrological response units:

topidx <- make.classes(topindex,16)

# the delay function is a bit more tricky because this requires cumulative fractions, but you generate it as follows:

n <- 5 # number of classes; a higher number will result in a smoother histogram
delay <- flowlength(huagrahuma.dem)*25 # TODO: add the outlet coordinates; otherwise the flowlength will be calculated to the edge of the map.
delay <- make.classes(delay, n)
delay <- delay[n:1,]
delay[,2] <- c(0, cumsum(delay[1:(n-1),2]))
############ PART 1: running the rainfall-runoff model ##############

## Load the example dataset from the Huagrahuma catchment
## and attach it to the search path

data(huagrahuma)
attach(huagrahuma)

## Initial exploration of the data:
str(huagrahuma)
topidx
parameters
rain

#I suspected the error was triggered by NA values which Qobs has. So I tried to convert NA to numerical values but ends in vain.  
k=1
for (i in Qobs) { 
  if (is.na(i)){               
    Qobs[k]<-Qobs[k-1]
  } 
  k<-k+1
}

####SCE-UA
set.seed(1)
fun=function(pars, topidx, delay, rain, ETp) topmodel:::topmodel(pars, topidx, delay, rain, ETp)
# Objective function, sud differences
OFUN = function(pars, topidx, delay, rain, ETp,Qobs) {
  Qsim=fun(pars, topidx, delay, rain, ETp)
  sum(abs(Qsim-Qobs)/Qobs)
  }
sceuares = rtop:::sceua(OFUN, pars = c(3.167914e-05,-5.990615e-01,2.129723e-02,2.626373e-02,0.05, 2.850000e+00,  1.000000e+03  ,1.199171e+03  ,9.361053e-03,7.235573e-01 ,2.500000e-01), lower = c(0,-7,0.001,0,0.005,0.001,50,50,0.0001,0,0.25), 
                        upper = c(0.0001,10,0.25,0.01,0.08,40,2000,2000,0.2,5,0.25),rain=rain,topidx=topidx,delay=delay,ETp=ETp,Qobs=Qobs)

>>>Error in if (sum(mapply(FUN = function(x, y, z) max(y - x, x - z, 0),  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You meet this problem because there exist same lower bounds and upper bounds,
as what you define them in your scripts (the last one of the vector, "0.25"):

```
lower = c(0,-7,0.001,0,0.005,0.001,50,50,0.0001,0,0.25)
upper = c(0.0001,10,0.25,0.01,0.08,40,2000,2000,0.2,5,0.25)
```

I met a similar problem "error in if (sum(mapply(FUN = function(x, y, z) max(y - x, x - z, 0)", and after I change my upper and lower bounds of parameters to be a correct range rather than a same value, the problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I found another package that also has sceua optimization function, named "hydromad". By using this, I was able to optimize TOPMODEL parameters. Here is the code when optimizing topmodel function from topmodel package with huagrahuma dataset.

hydromad | Hydrological Model Assessment and Development 
http://hydromad.catchment.org/#SCEoptim

```
install.packages("hydromad", repos="http://hydromad.catchment.org",dependencies = TRUE)
library(hydromad)


## Objective function
OFUN = function(pars, topidx, delay, rain, ETp,Qobs) {
  Qsim<-topmodel:::topmodel(pars, topidx, delay, rain, ETp)
  k<-1     
  cnt<-0
  obj<-0    
  for (i in Qobs) {   #In order to ignore timesteps Qobs = NA
    if (is.na(i)){               
      obj<-obj
    } else{
      obj<-obj + abs(Qsim[k] - i)/i #using relative error as Objective function
      cnt<-cnt+1
    }
    k<-k+1
  }
  obj/cnt
}

sceuares =SCEoptim(OFUN, par = c(3.167914e-05,-5.990615e-01,2.129723e-02,2.626373e-02,0.05, 2.850000e+00,  1.000000e+03  ,1.199171e+03  ,9.361053e-03,7.235573e-01 ,2.500000e-01), lower = c(0,-7,0.001,0,0.005,0.001,50,50,0.0001,0,0.25), 
         upper = c(0.0001,10,0.25,0.01,0.08,40,2000,2000,0.2,5,0.25),rain=rain,topidx=topidx,delay=delay,ETp=ETp,Qobs=Qobs, control = list())
 
 ## run the model and visualize the outcome:
 
 Qsim <- topmodel(sceuares$par, topidx, delay, rain, ETp)
 plot(Qsim, type="l", col="red")
 points(Qobs)
 
 ## Evaluate the model 
 NSeff(Qobs, Qsim) #Nash-Sutcliffe efficiency
 100*sceuares$value #MeanAbsolutePercentageError
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Y7aV.png)
Model output with initial parameters
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJmzs.png)
Model output with optimized parameters by sceua
Redline is model output (Qsim).
plots are Qobs.